# Помогите найти файл конфигурации mariadb centos 7

Tags: mariadb, centos7

Все перерыл не могу найти ни my.cnf, ни my.ini

Answer (score 0):

## Если демон `mysql` уже запущен, и есть подозрение на использование произвольного конфига

В bash пишем:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

Получаем вывод, похожий на этот:

```
mysql    65289  1.0 58.7 4963428 2299528 ?     Sl   Feb07 1256:45 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Ищем строку `--defaults-file` или `--defaults-extra-file`. Если ее нет, либо вообще нет параметров, значит используется конфиг по-умолчанию.

Дополнительно можно посмотреть переменные окружения (интересует `MYSQL_HOME`). В моем примере PID процесса 65289 (`ps aux` - второй параметр). Выполняем

```
# так можно получить переменные окружения работающего mysql
sudo cat /proc/65289/environ
```

## Если используется конфиг по-умолчанию

Проверяем файлы:

- `/etc/my.cnf`
- `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- `SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf` для CentOS это `SYSCONFDIR = /etc`
- `$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf` `$MYSQL_HOME` - должна быть установлена в переменных окружения

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее всего было бы поискать на диске поиском:

```
find / -name my.cnf
```

если его вообще нет, то создай его в /etc/my.cnf
и пропиши всё, что тебе нужно.

А параметру по у молчанию берутся из файла загрузки сервиса:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service
```